# Property of continuous functions and monotonic functions on disconnected sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $S=[0,1)\cup [2,3]$ and $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$ be strictly increasing and $f(S)$ be connected. Then, is $f$ continuous? If so, why?

Am totally helpless. I think the proof/disproof has something to do with the property that image of connected set is connected and the monotonicity. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42595237#42595237